# Different behavior on ROUND() based on number format

Tags: sql, sql-server

Executing the following:

```
SELECT ROUND(0.825,2)
```

RETURNS 0.830

Executing the following:

```
SELECT ROUND(CAST(0.825 AS FLOAT),2)
```

RETURNS 0.82

How is this behavior explained and how can be overcomed when I want to round a float field to 2 decimals?

Comment: The number in `SELECT ROUND(0.825,2)` isn't a float. That number *can't* be represented as a float

Comment: Likely the same as this very recent question https://stackoverflow.com/q/76523794/73226

Comment: Yes, seems exactly so

Comment: @ThomA I changed your answer-in-a-comment to an answer.  Upvote it, or add your own and I'll upvote it and we can close this one as a dupe.